# JQuery in ASP.Net User Control in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, user-controls

I'm having problems using JQuery inside an ASP.Net User Control  I've created a sample and here is the markup for my user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="UC" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="UC.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_UC" %>

<span id="Licenses"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ctlID = $("span[id$='Licenses']");
        ctlID.text = "Testing";
    });
</script>
```

If I include this script tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" />` in the aspx file containing the user control to reference JQuery, nothing happens. If I don't include it, I get a JavaScript error dialog saying there was a runtime error and that an Object was expected.  Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you try to call `$("span[id$='Licenses']")` from the FireBug console? Does it work?

Comment: Is `js/jquery-1.3.2.js` the correct path relative to the containing `aspx` page? Fiddler it, or better Firebug it.

Comment: I've included the reference to js/jquery-1.3.2.js in a <script> tag in the head section of the containing aspx file - is this not the correct place for it?  It appears that may be causing problems.  If I remark that out, then I get the javascript error dialog, if I un-remark it then nothing happens.

Comment: Are there any javascript errors on the page when the script reference is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text is a function in jQuery.  Try:

```
 ctlID.text("Testing");
```

Comment: This works either as a function call or assignment as long as I run it directly from the aspx page.  Neither method works when run from the user control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the jquery library correctly on master page?

Is that not meant to be dollar before id, i.e. `$id='Licenses'`  ? or even a `#`

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing the '$' to the id gets all elements that ends with "Licenses" .

Make a quick change to test this to '#' will get you exactly one element.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var ctlID = $("#Licenses");
        ctlID.text = "Testing";
    });
```

To make it work with attribute selector try

```
$('span[@id=Licenses]')   // You can omit the @ in the latest version of jquery.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this:

```
var ctlID = $("span[id$='Licenses']").get(0);
ctlID.text = "Testing";
```